# Архитектура веб приложения

Tags: java, веб-программирование, архитектура

Сейчас есть веб-приложение (Java + Tomcat), которое представляет собой карту, со всякими статистиками и выводом объектов.

Сейчас мне нужно добавить вторую страницу для этого приложения, которая будет представлять собой ту же карту, но с выводом на нее принципиально других объектов и другой логикой взаимодействия.

У меня навязчивое желание сделать эту страницу отдельным проектом.

**Плюсы такого подхода:**

- Обе страницы слабо коррелируют между собой. А те объекты, которые выводятся на обе страницы все равно отображаются по разному
- Я получаю два независимых приложения, которые будет проще поддерживать

**Минусы:**

- Примерно 10% java кода у них общие. Скорее всего этот код придется выделять в отдельный модуль
- Где-то 40% фронтенда у них общие. Это CSS стили, сервисные функции JS, тот же вывод и взаимодействие с картой.

**Вопрос:** как лучше поступить: выделить это в отдельное приложение или писать все в одном проекте?

Comment: Это что одностраничное приложение?

Comment: @RomanC да. Вся логика реализована на аяксе и веб сокетах

Comment: если у вас одностраничное приложение, то есть фронт и бекенд даже собираются отдельно и деплоятся отдельно, то их может имеет смысл держать в 2 репозиториях. Делить же фронт на 2 репозитория нет абсолютно никакого смысла.

Comment: фронт и бекенд могут и вместе деплиться; это от архитектуры зависит, и от ролей/команд

Answer (score 0):

Репозиторий я бы оставил общий.

А сборку можно отдельную или общую. Вопрос в том, если возникает желание деплоить раздельно, "не трогая часть, которая работает".

Еще это вопрос распределения ответственности при коммандной разработке, чтоб не полуалось, что оно такое большое, что никто один не может представить, как оно работает.

---

Репозиторий общий, разбит на модули. Часть файлов общая получается.
Два разных корневых модуля. По зависимостям -- два (или больше) множества модулей, которые пересекаются. Выкладывать каждое множество можно отдельно.

Можно еще группы модулей (по разработчикам)

---

Есть противоположный подход: всё раздельное, синхронизация через git-tree.
Но я его не пробовал.

Comment: А как синхронизировать те же css файлы? Если нужно вносить изменения в оба проекта?

Comment: добавил еще инфы

Answer (score 0):

Я бы на вашем месте оставил все в одном проекте. Потому что из за добавления одной страницы вы хотите улучшить архитектуру с разделением на фронтэнд и бэкенд. Но это улучшение требует гораздо больше времени и возможно ресурсов, которое следует планировать.

Если у вас много общего статического контента, то имет смысл деплоить его отдельно или сделать из него общий загрузчик статического контента.

Во всяком случае вручную это делать очень тяжело, и как правило следует воспользоваться готовыми фреймворками на фронте  типа ангуляр или реакт, и на бэке.

Разделять монолит на модули с последующей сборкой абсолютно бессмысленно.

Comment: Разделять монолит на модули может иметь смысл, например, если делаются похожие проекты для разных заказчиков, но не просто ядро+проект, а пересекающиеся множества фич (АБ,БВ,АВ)

Comment: Есть разные вещи, одно строить проект из модулей, другое разламывать его на модули. Если в первом случае используется модульная архитектура, то во втором ее отсутствие и следовательно разбиение на компоненты, дублирование кода и т.д. подобные баги. Если изначально выбрана одна архитектура, то рефакторинг возможен, но обойдется дорого.